# How to use JSONpath to extract specific values

Tags: jmeter, jsonpath

I'm using JSONpath to try and find data with an array of JSON objects but I'm struggling to get to the information I want. The array contains many objects similar to below where there are values for RecID throughout. If I use `$..RecID` I get them all when I only want the first `Key.RecID` of each object (with a value **1338438** in this example). Is there a way to only extract the top level `Key.RecID` value?

BTW I'm trying to do this in jMeter and I'm assuming JSONpath is the best way to do what I want but if there is a better way I'd be happy to hear about it.

Thanks in advance

```json
[{
    "Key": {
        "RecID": 1338438
    },
    "Users": [{
            "FullName": "Miss Burns",
            "Users": {
                "Key": {
                    "Name": "Burns",
                    "RecID": 1317474
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "FullName": "Mrs Fisher",
            "Users": {
                "Key": {
                    "Name": "Fisher",
                    "RecID": 1317904
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "User": {
        "FullName": "Mrs Fisher",
        "Key": {
            "Name": "Fisher",
            "RecID": 1317904
        }
    },
    "Organisation": {
        "Key": {
            "RecID": 1313881
        }
    }
}]
```

Comment: Access using the array index `$[0].Key.RecID`

Comment: Thanks Akshay. $[*].Key.RecID gives me all the top level RecIDs which is what I wanted :-)